# Why are the contour lines in filled.contour() not exactly the same than those from contour()?

Tags: r, contour

I am tyring to add contour lines with `contour()` to a `filled.contour()` plot and would have expected the lines to be the same from both functions. But this is not always the case as can be seen in this example, which has some details slighlty different. E.g. some of the white area around x=4/y=4 and the purple area around x=6/y=3 are without black lines: [image: lines and filled contours differ] 

I used the following code for the plot above, which uses random numbers, hence it will slighlty differ for a different set of random numbers:

```r
x<-1:10
y<-1:10
z<-matrix(x*y+rnorm(100,10,10),nrow=length(x),ncol=length(y))
filled.contour(x,y,z, nlevels = 5,
    plot.axes = {
        contour(x,y,z, nlevels = 5, frame.plot = FALSE, add = TRUE);
        axis(1); axis(2)
        })
```

Why are the black `contour()` lines not exactly following the `filled.contour()` areas? Is there a way to add lines between `filled.contour` areas without using `contour()` or can the way how the lines are determined be controlled such that lines are shown when `filled.contour` shows a different colour?

Comment: Tricky one, might require going inside the contour function. I would suggest two things: 1. use `set.seed()` function e.g. `set.seed(1)` to make your sampling reproducible. 2. See what `ggplot2` alternative has to offer, lots of support from the community for this package: https://www.r-statistics.com/2016/07/using-2d-contour-plots-within-ggplot2-to-visualize-relationships-between-three-variables/